# Save Wikipedia table as an image

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Is it possible to retrieve a table from Wikipedia as an image?

Example here, in the Wikipedia page for the [iPhone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone), there is a big table in the "[model comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices#iPhone)" section.

Comment: In what language? Or just using the api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I would do it, is scrub the required html with javascript or some other language http client (in my case because I like ruby and since you don't specify I would use [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html)) get to the table html traversing the DOM `<table class= "wikitable">` make a new local html document with the table you just scrubbed, and be sure to include css and assets so it looks good, save it and then use something like [WebVector](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/webvector/) (this is for Java as per your comment, but it can be done in other languages) to convert that html with the table alone into a PNG

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible through the API nor any special pages on Wikipedia.